# build hello world using Boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost, makefile

I am just learning using Boost.Python, so excuse me if it seems silly.
I have these code from [here](http://pyengr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inter/bpy/) to wrap a c++ function in python.
I also searched for a few hours to find a working example and most relevant question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003506/how-to-build-a-boost-dependent-project-using-regular-makefiles), but still I have problem with build and run.

This is **zoo.cpp**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

/*
 * This is the C++ function we write and want to expose to Python.
 */
const std::string hello() {
    return std::string("hello, zoo");
}

/*
 * This is a macro Boost.Python provides to signify a Python extension module.
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(zoo) {
    // An established convention for using boost.python.
    using namespace boost::python;

    // Expose the function hello().
    def("hello", hello);
}
```

and  **visit_zoo.py**

```
import zoo
# In zoo.cpp we expose hello() function, and it now exists in the zoo module.
assert 'hello' in dir(zoo)
# zoo.hello is a callable.
assert callable(zoo.hello)
# Call the C++ hello() function from Python.
print zoo.hello()
```

and here is the **makefile**

```
CC = g++
PYLIBPATH = $(shell python-config --exec-prefix)/lib
LIB = -L$(PYLIBPATH) $(shell python-config --libs) -lboost_python
OPTS = $(shell python-config --include) -O2

default: zoo.so
    @python ./visit_zoo.py

zoo.so: zoo.o
    $(CC) $(LIB) -Wl,-rpath,$(PYLIBPATH) -shared $< -o $@

zoo.o: zoo.cpp Makefile
    $(CC) $(OPTS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.so *.o

.PHONY: default clean
```

**error massage:**

```
g++ Usage: /usr/bin/python-config --prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--configdir -O2 -c zoo.cpp -o zoo.o
g++: error: Usage:: No such file or directory
g++: error: missing argument to ‘--prefix’
/bin/sh: 1: --exec-prefix: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --includes: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --libs: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --cflags: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --ldflags: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --extension-suffix: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --help: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --configdir: not found
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'zoo.o' failed
make: *** [zoo.o] Error 127
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Boost.Python, as the usage line shows, `python-config --include` in your Makefile should be `python-config --includes`

Answer (score 0):

I used this makefile that worked. Thanks for reading. I got help from [here](https://shocksolution.com/python-basics-tutorials-and-examples/linking-python-and-c-with-boostpython/)

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = zoo

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    # g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python-$(PYTHON_VERSION) -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so
    g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp
```